# Custom attribute text in Magento Cart Crosselling

Tags: magento, attributes, cart

Currently I have this in crosselling.phtml:

```
  <?php if($this->getItemCount()): ?>
<div class="crosssell">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Service:') ?></h2>
    <ul id="crosssell-products-list">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="product-details">
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>

                    <p><?php
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $custom->getAttributeText('servicetekst');
?></p>
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <ul class="add-to-links">               
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('crosssell-products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything loads fine, except de custom attribute "servicetekst". From here, I'm unsure how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked for me for displaying custom attributes in crossell template Magento 1.9.2.2. It's easy.

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getCustom_attribute()) ?>
```

Make sure "Used in Product Listing" is set to "Yes" and reindex.